# How often is functions.php loaded?

Tags: functions

Trying to get my head round functions.php and am wondering how often it is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is once. As any other PHP file otherwise it would likely cause crash because of function redefinitions.

More complex answer is there can be actually two different `functions.php` loading - one for parent theme and one for child theme. Tricky part here is that child theme's loads before the parent's, which can at times be counter-intuitive for some purposes (like working with hooks).

Comment: Thanks! So if I'm not using child themes, it only gets called once per session, install of theme, admin page view? Not quite clear.

Comment: Once per WordPress engine load. It is included in `wp-settings.php`, which is early in loading process and is not conditional.

Comment: And what triggers the WordPress engine load event?

For example, do I need to uninstall and reinstall a theme to trigger functions.php to be re-loaded?

Comment: No, its loaded on every pageview, whether admin or front-end.

Comment: Ahah. I see now.